# Multiple fetch requests with complex predicates

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I have a couple of views which present data from a CoreData entity in my app. To retrieve the data required for the views I often have to implement multiple fetchRequests which feels wrong - perhaps I'm still making basic mistakes like thinking of CoreData in too much of a SQL database sense.

In fact for one of my views I have 22 fetch requests which may well be the correct way of achieving what I need but as an iPhone/Objective-C novice I can't help questioning my approach. Here is a snippet of my code showing 2 of many fetchRequest, could you give me a nudge in the right direction if I am doing it wrong?

```
      SGK_T4T_01AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entityDiscription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Sessions" inManagedObjectContext:context];

//Swim 3 Count
        NSFetchRequest *request2 = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        [request2 setEntity:entityDiscription];
        [request2 setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
        NSExpression *keyPathExpression2 = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"sport"];
        NSExpression *swimCountExpression = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"count:" arguments:[NSArray arrayWithObject:keyPathExpression2]];
        NSExpressionDescription *expressionDescription2 = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
        [expressionDescription2 setName:@"swimCount"];
        [expressionDescription2 setExpression:swimCountExpression];
        [expressionDescription2 setExpressionResultType:NSInteger16AttributeType];
        [request2 setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:expressionDescription2]];
        NSPredicate *pred2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(date >= %@ AND sport like %@)", swimSinceDateAsDate, sportTypeSwim];
        [request2 setPredicate:pred2];

        NSError *error2;
        NSArray *objects2 = [context executeFetchRequest:request2 error:&error2];
        if (objects2 == nil) {
            NSLog(@"The fetch request returned an array == nil");
        } else {
            _swimTotalSwimCountLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [[objects2 objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"swimCount"]];
        }

        //Swim 4 Fastest 1500m Time Trial
        NSFetchRequest *request3 = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        [request3 setEntity:entityDiscription];
        [request3 setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
        NSExpression *keyPathExpression3 = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"time1"];
        NSExpression *swimfastest1500Expression = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"min:" arguments:[NSArray arrayWithObject:keyPathExpression3]];
        NSExpressionDescription *expressionDescription3 = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
        [expressionDescription3 setName:@"swimFastest1500"];
        [expressionDescription3 setExpression:swimfastest1500Expression];
        [expressionDescription3 setExpressionResultType:NSInteger16AttributeType];
        [request3 setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:expressionDescription3]];
        NSString *sessType3 = @"Time Trial - 1500m";
        NSPredicate *pred3 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(date >= %@ AND sport like %@ AND sessiontype like %@)", swimSinceDateAsDate, sportTypeSwim, sessType3];
        [request3 setPredicate:pred3];

        NSError *error3;
        NSArray *objects3 = [context executeFetchRequest:request3 error:&error3];
        if (objects3 == nil) {
            NSLog(@"The fetch request returned an array == nil");
        } else {
            NSUInteger durationInSeconds = [[[objects3 objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"swimFastest1500"] integerValue];
            NSUInteger durationInMinutes = durationInSeconds / 60;
            NSUInteger durationRemainder = durationInSeconds % 60;
            _swimTt1500PaceLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%02i:%02i", durationInMinutes, durationRemainder];
        }
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance, links or direction you may be able to provide...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The predicate stuff doesn't look too bad - but may I ask why you're limiting to all those NSExpressionDescriptions? Did you analyze and find that by limiting to just those properties you found concrete performance improvements? Core Data is usually pretty good at faulting/optimizing your memory, and that might clean up the statements quite a bit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - in answer to your question, when I analysed my app it came up with no errors, all green. I'm not sure that I follow your statement "limiting to all those NSExDesc". Still too much of a novice but I am always looking for ways to clean-up my code, so if you have a moment to elaborate it would be very much appreciated...

Comment: Absolutely - and good on you for running analyze. We flip that on for all our builds (slower builds, but no technical debt creeping in :).  The NSExpression stuff is actually pretty cool (and looks like it might achieve higher performance) but is verbose. We have a fair number of entities/fetches, and run performance checks.. and have not used those yet. You could remove those (less code), but maybe less performance? You'd have to use Instruments before/after to know how much you're gaining for the additional lines added there. :)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond Scott, I'll look into your recommendation...